# Inconsistent insert speed of batch update to temp table in MySQL (with jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate)

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

I have MariaDb instance and a temporary table. The workflow:

1. Start transaction
2. Drop temp table if exists, create temp table
3. insert 40K records to it using `insert into TEMP1 (xxx,yyy) values(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?)...`
4. process this data somehow
5. End transaction

Worflow is performed in one thread. 
Problem definition: First run of this workflow inserts 40K records within 1-3 seconds, all consecutive runs insert 40K within 30-40 seconds.

Can anybody tell how to make it run 1-3 seconds for all runs?

Table definition:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEMP1 (
uuid varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
raw_content longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
security_level varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
key_name varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
stage_user_uuid varchar(80) NOT NULL,
data_type varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
string_value varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
integer_value bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
double_value double DEFAULT NULL,
date_value datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
INDEX user_uuid_idx (stage_user_uuid)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Are you sure the `CREATE` does not terminate the transaction?

Comment: No `PRIMARY KEY` on the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I used `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate` which worked in a very strange way. I have setting `rewriteBatchedStatements=true`.

1st run really executed statement like this

```
insert into TEMP1 (xxx,yyy) values(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?);
```

Next statements for an unknown reason executed statements one by one

```
insert into TEMP1 (xxx,yyy) values(?,?);
insert into TEMP1 (xxx,yyy) values(?,?);
insert into TEMP1 (xxx,yyy) values(?,?);
```

Which caused the slowness.

Actual statements can be seen in logs with this suffix to connection string: `&logger=com.mysql.jdbc.log.Slf4JLogger&profileSQL=true`

I end up with regular prepared statement batch and it worked perfectly.

```
ps.addBatch()
ps.executeBatch()
ps.clearBatch()
```

Underlying the problem is `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate` uses `JdbcUtils.supportsBatchUpdates` which fails for some reason. I use `org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:8.0.30` pool

```
driver 'supportsBatchUpdates' method threw exception
java.sql.SQLException: PooledConnection has already been closed.
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.supportsBatchUpdates(JdbcUtils.java:359)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:897)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:890)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:589)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:890)
```

Answer (score -1):

The number of indexes on a table is the most dominant factor for insert performance. The more indexes a table has, the slower the execution becomes. The insert statement is the only operation that cannot directly benefit from indexing because it has no where clause.

If there are indexes on the table, the database must make sure the new entry is also found via these indexes. For this reason it has to add the new entry to each and every index on that table. The number of indexes is therefore a multiplier for the cost of an insert statement.

To optimize insert performance, it is very important to keep the number of indexes small.

Read more [here](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/dml/insert).

Comment: Its a temp table therefore index don't grow from consecutive runs. Question is why insert time is so much different for similar operations.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it's not useful for this question and felt like you posted it just to get rating up without much concern to question details. Though your comment put me into digging client code that executes statements and I found what's wrong. If your answer was about it initially it would certainly be the solution.